# Android - program play button to continue reading the media if it already is paused

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to program my play button to continue reading the media if it already is paused by mu pause button.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to understand. What do you mean by "continue reading media"? That you want to resume playback..?

Comment: My media is paused by button pause with method pause(). I want play media in time resume. Thanks.